# Adjust UIImage with Aspect Ratio using Autolayout

Tags: ios, uiimage, uicollectionviewcell, ios-autolayout

Is it possible to automatically resize uiimage based on autolayout with aspect ratio (1:1)?

Btw I'm using collectionview as my view.

**Here's my layout in storyboard**

[image: Storyboard]

**and here's the result when running the app**

[image: CollectionView]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add as in picture to make image sacrifice width to fit to aspect ratio constraint

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the `UIImageView` to always be a square and set the an aspect ratio on the width and height.

However if you want to resize the `UIImage` depending on the size of the imageView then in your custom `UICollectionViewCell` make the necessary adjustments in the `layoutSubviews()`. Here you can inspect the size of the 
`UIImageView`

.